# Which project type to select if I just want to use command line fro Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to start learning C# and just want to use the command line, like the option offered by Xcode when you are choosing which project type. I do not want to make an app or anything of the sort, just want to use command line where I can print strings and read in inputs from the keyboard. Which project type do I select in order to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Other` / `.Net` / `Console Project`** (& choose a language other than C# if needed)

[image]